# Speeding up Batch file parsing time

Tags: performance, file, parsing, batch-file

I have a batch file which reads from multiple csv files and cleans up the data a bit and creates another csv file with cleansed data. It runs fine and does the job but pretty slow. Can you help to speed this up? 2 files are about 2500 KB and one file is about 25,000 KB.

#### Here's the batch file:

```
@echo "Cleansing TU DATA" &setlocal
set /p "header="<"SS1218 UBP FF TU.csv">"TU_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%header%
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=, tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("SS1218 UBP FF TU.csv") do (
  if "%%a" NEQ "MINMAX" (
    >>"TU_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d
  )
)
@echo "Cleansing EXP DATA"
set /p "header="<"SS1218_FF_UBP_EXP.csv">"EXP_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%header%
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=, tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("SS1218_FF_UBP_EXP.csv") do (
  if NOT "%%a" IN ("MINMAX", "TWOWAY") (
    >>"EXP_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d
  )
)
```

---

#### Here's the sample data:

```
MINMAX,TU,ACXNDBK_RE,1.34537949,0,125,1607539
MINMAX,TU,ACXNDCLI_RE,0,0,0,1607539
MINMAX,TU,ACXNDCO_RE,6.0407280943,0,451,1607539
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,700001-800000,7,0.0004354482
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,800001-900000,3,0.0001866207
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,900001-999998,3,0.0001866207
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,999999,14,0.0008708964
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,BLANKS,0,0
ONEWAY,TU,CS_H606_RE,I,0,0
```

Basically removes all `MINMAX` rows and gives me `ONEWAY` rows in a new file.

Comment: Updated the code formatting

Comment: @aduguid but you forgot to indent two echo commands, so they are attached to the previous line....

Comment: To drop lines from a file I'd use `findstr /v "^MINIMAX" infile >outfile` or switch to powershell (due to findstr size limitations).

Comment: I don't think that the `if NOT "%%a" IN ("MINMAX", "TWOWAY") (` command runs fine in a Batch file...

Comment: Also, when checking strings, I'd recommend you use the following syntax, `If /I Not "%%a"=="MINMAX"`.

Comment: I agree with LotPings - definitely try `findstr /v`. If that's still too slow and you're open to trying non-batch solutions, I find that Perl parses text extremely quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

@echo "Cleansing TU DATA"
set /p "header=" < "SS1218 UBP FF TU.csv"
> "TU_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%header%

(
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=, tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("SS1218 UBP FF TU.csv") do (
    if "%%~a" NEQ "MINMAX" >&3 echo.%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d
  )
) 3>> "TU_UBP_SS1218.csv"

@echo "Cleansing EXP DATA"
set /p "header=" < "SS1218_FF_UBP_EXP.csv"
> "EXP_UBP_SS1218.csv" echo.%header%

(
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=, tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("SS1218_FF_UBP_EXP.csv") do (
    if NOT "%%~a" == "MINMAX" if not "%%~a" == "TWOWAY" >&3 echo.%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d
  )
) 3>> "EXP_UBP_SS1218.csv"
```

Setting variable `header` and expanding `%header%` on the same line
is not using the immediate value as `%header%` is being expanded on
evaluation parse rather than the execution parse. Fix is to break
the line into 2 separate lines.

Each `for` loop is inserted between parentheses and redirects
the echoes as a whole, so it should be faster as the file
remains open until end of the parenthese block.

Comparison of `"%%~a"` fixed by comparing to each value separately.

The echoed data is using stream 3 so that the echoed code can be
viewed if using `echo on` to debug the script.

Comment: +1, You have shown important ways to speed up the OP's existing code. However, there is no need to use file handle 3. You can simply redirect stdout directly to the output file at the outer parenthesized block, and within the loop `ECHO` normally, without any further redirection. More importantly, there is a much faster way to achieve the overall goal with `FINDSTR`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068619/1012053)

Comment: @dbenham, thanks. Using handle 3, as mentioned in the answer, is to view all commands if echo is on. With the test data supplied with a header inserted, the echoed commands and empty lines with using handle 3 total 53 lines. Handle 1 (*default*) totals 17 lines. It works either way in this example, though inspecting how it works, with echo on, is suppressed with using handle 1 as it redirects the enclosed commands along with the echoed text.

Comment: Good point. I didn't pay enough attention to notice the lack of ECHO OFF. Your use of handle 3 is indeed required in the absence of ECHO OFF.

Answer (score 1):

[Michael shows how to speed up your existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056474/1012053). But there is a much better way.

First off, I don't think there is any need to treat your header rows separately. You are excluding rows that begin with MINMAX or TWOWAY, and I'm pretty sure your header rows will not begin with either of those values.

More importantly, FINDSTR is a ***much*** faster alternative for filtering out unwanted rows. The `/V` option excludes rows that match the search, and the `/B` option only matches the beginning of each row. The search argument is space delimited, so the second `FINDSTR` excludes rows that match either string. I added the trailing comma to each search string, just to make sure the column value is an exact match, though I doubt in your case it would make a difference. For example, without the comma, the `FINDSTR` would exclude rows that begin with `TWOWAY` and `TWOWAYS`.

```
@echo off
echo Cleansing TU DATA
findstr /v /b "MINMAX," "SS1218 UBP FF TU.csv" >"TU_UBP_SS1218.csv"
findstr /v /b "MINMAX, TWOWAY," "SS1218_FF_UBP_EXP.csv" >"EXP_UBP_SS1218.csv"
```